# Eclipse not finding main method when trying to export to runnable JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I am trying to include some external dependencies in my JAR file when I export from eclipse, so I'm using the "Runnable JAR" export option. But when I choose my configuration to export and click "Finish", I get [these errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSixq.png). That configuration runs completely fine when I use `Right Click > Run As` on the class, and my main method is [right here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUpDx.png) in the file I told Eclipse to look in. What could I be doing wrong when I export?

[Here's my run configuration.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDdLA.png)

Comment: Show us your run configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the latest versions of Java after JDK 9 cause some kind of problems with Eclipse, and I was able to export after switching to JDK 8.